# What does "he'd never meant any of it" mean in this context?

Tags: sentence-meaning

> "I have heard Dad talking about him," said George. "He(Lucius Malfoy) was a big supporter of You-Know-Who."
>
> "And when You-Know-Who disappeared," said Fred, craning around to look at Harry, "Lucius Malfoy came back saying **he'd never meant any of it**. Load of dung - Dad reckons he was right in You-Know-Who's inner circle."

I have no idea what "**he'd never meant any of it**" means in this context? Is it an idiom? But I can't find it anywhere. Maybe, I don't know what "meant any of it" refers to.

-- Excerpted from Harry Potter.

Comment: could you share what particular about the sentence trips you up? "He came back saying he had never done X." - Is that as intractable, or is the hard part the 'any', or what?

Comment: @bukwyrm, maybe, I don't know what "meant any of it" refers to. Originally, I simply have no idea why Fred said it. I just added it into my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"*He'd never meant any of it*" in this context means that "he" is *retracting* what he previously said.

It seems that prior to the disappearance of *You-Know-Who*, Lucius Malfoy was vocally supportive of him; but after *You-Know-Who* disappeared, Lucius Malfoy claimed that he had not really meant the supportive things he had said.

Comment: perhaps the meaning of 'to mean sth.' is unclear - you might want to add it explicitly to your answer. I.e. 'to say something and mean it' > Saying something that includes either a belief that is dearly held, or a set of actions that the speaker is prepared to execute.

Comment: He's not really *retracting* his words. Rather, he's saying that he was not being genuine or sincere when he said them.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Is a retraction not taking back one's words? Anyway, in this case, the narrator believes it is the *retraction* that is insincere. He goes on to say that his father thought the retraction was a "load of dung" and that Lucius was in *You Know Who*'s inner circle. If it weren't for that detail then you might be right.

Comment: "Lucius Malfoy came back saying he'd never meant any of it."  is a report of what Malfoy was saying. What is being reported is that Malfoy was claiming that he had not been sincere when he said those words.  He's not retracting his words.  That would require an admission that he had been wrong to say them. Rather, he's saying that he wasn't sincere when he spoke them.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo Yes, Lucius is *claiming* he wasn't sincere when he spoke the words (of support) originally, but the narrator's father believed that it was the retraction, not the original words, that was insincere.

Comment: Is there anything in the quote to indicate that Malfoy was acting honorably and retracting words he had spoken in earnest, once he realized he was wrong? I don't see it. Rather, he seems to have been acting dodgy and saying that his words of support had never been in earnest in the first place.

Comment: @Astralbee When you say "...his father thought the retraction was a "load of dung"...", do you mean "load of dung" was said by his father? I thought that was said by Fred, which might be the opinion of Fred's, instead of his father's. What do you think?

Comment: @dan Now you say that, without any further context I agree it could mean either. However if it *is* "Fred's" opinion it was clearly based on what his father said about Lucius being in that "inner circle", so even in that case it is indirectly his father's thoughts. I haven't read Harry Potter, I'm an adult. :)